# Javafx 8 ListView how to show rows when no items are in the list

Tags: listview, javafx-8

I have a listview and I would like to show the rows already when I have no items. Do I really have to add null one time and when an item is added remove that null or is there an other possibility to do that?

Comment: You can add a placeholder

Comment: @jpell yes I know but that's not what I want, I just want an empty list with the rows already shown

Comment: @jpell That's doesn't work. Still got an empty listview wthout any rows shown

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have (I can add placeholder but I won't do that)
[empty list now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wYNe.png)

This is what I want to have
[empty list with rows shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77xea.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with **an empty ListView with some additional styling as a placeholder** for my main ListView.

This way you avoid messing with your ListView's items.

Create a class similar to this (this one is in Kotlin):

```
class ListViewPlaceholder: ListView<Any?>() {
    init {
        style = "-fx-background-insets: 0; -fx-padding: 0;"
        items.add(null)
        cellFactory = Callback<ListView<Any?>?, ListCell<Any?>?> {
            object : ListCell<Any?>() {
                override fun updateItem(item: Any?, empty: Boolean) {
                    super.updateItem(item, true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Set **background insets** and **padding** to 0 - it removes placeholder ListView's border so it renders exactly where the main ListView (which already has a border of its own).

Add `null` to the list.

Set new cell factory and return a `ListCell` with overridden `updateItem` method where you call super method with `true` as the second parameter. **This is required for the first item in the list to look like an empty cell and not like a cell with null item.**

Then you can use it in your fxml like this:

```
<ListView fx:id="mainListView">
    <placeholder>
        <ListViewPlaceholder/>
    </placeholder>
</ListView>
```

or in code:

```
mainListView.placeholder = ListViewPlaceholder()
```

---

With this styling

```
.list-cell {
    -fx-border-color: red;
    -fx-border-insets: 2;
}

.list-cell:empty {
    -fx-border-color: orange;
}
```

Result looks like this

Main ListView empty - shows placeholder:

[image: no items]

Main ListView has one item:

[image: one item]